# [Python]-Why is the output being printed on terminal with no "print()" func in comparison to i.e. VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, io, printf

So I have this question where I'm able to print the output with no `print()` function on bash or cmd, for example when I write this code on terminal:

```
__name__
```

I would get the output:

```
__main__
```

with no `print()` func needed. But if I'd want to do the same on my IDE which in my case is VS Code, I should do the following in order to print the same output:

```
print(__name__)
```

So what's the reason for this?
I'm very new to programming and I don't know much about CS concepts, so please explain in simple terms, Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're using the _Interactive Interpreter_ -  it automatically prints the result of the last statement executed

Comment: Look into "Python REPL"